# Fyber Rewarded Videos and offerwall iOS

Tags: ios, rewardedvideoad, fyber

I am working on the Fyber SDK to show offer wall and reward videos. I have implemented proper code for it by following its documentation. Earlier it was showing the Game Ads properly but suddenly it stopped working. I am unable to find the reason behind it. Now I have added two ad networks i.e. Facebook audience and AdMob (Refer attachment)

[[image: Ad Netwroks[1]][image: Ad Control]

I am getting following error:

- [FYB Info]: RV client asks to validate a TPN: facebookaudiencenetwork
- [FYB Info]: Provider facebookaudiencenetwork integrated: NO
- [FYB Info]: Videos from facebookaudiencenetwork validation result:
  no_sdk
- [FYB Info]: RV client asks to validate a TPN: admob
- [FYB Info]: Provider admob integrated: NO
- [FYB Info]: Videos from admob validation result: no_sdk
- [FYB Error]: No video offers are available

Comment: You did not show your code, but is it missing important line: `#import "FyberSDK.h"`? Just because of those no_sdk lines..

Answer (score 0):

**This should work** for `facebookaudiencenetwork`

Call [FBAdSettings bidderToken] from the iOS Audience Network SDK. The token is valid for the lifespan of the application process. Also, pass the IDFA in the device.ifa field with [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString].

`AdMob` as the network/mediation platform currently only supports client-side callbacks, not server-side callbacks.

**Alternative solution**

AdMob Rewarded video is also currently supported via MoPub and IronSource mediation platforms, and my understanding is both platforms support taking AdMob's client-side callback and converting it into a server-side callback for you.

[Source for more details](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/issues/47)